# I wish to make the message "game over. failed to press button" appear once the timer reaches zero

Tags: vb.net

'below is what needs to be displayed once the timer reaches zero, the timer label should stop and the message : Game over, failed to press button appears'

```
    Me.Controls.Add(time)
    time.Location = New Point(30, 150)
    time.BringToFront()
    'OVER'
    Dim over As New Label() With {
       .Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 13, FontStyle.Bold),
       .Height = 400,
       .Width = 400,
       .ForeColor = Color.Red,
    .Text = "GAME OVER. FAILED TO PRESS BUTTON"
   }

    Me.Controls.Add(over)
    over.Location = New Point(30, 100)
    over.BringToFront()
    over.Hide()

    Dim over As New Label() With {
       .Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 13, FontStyle.Bold),
       .Height = 400,
       .Width = 400,
       .ForeColor = Color.Red,
    .Text = 2
   }

    Me.Controls.Add(over)
    over.Location = New Point(50, 100)
    over.BringToFront()
    over.Hide()

    Timer1.Start()
```

'at this point when the timer1 ,which is displayed by label1, reaches zero but the following does not occur'

```
    If Label1.Text = 0 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Label1.Hide()
        over.BringToFront()
        over.Show()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text - 1

End Sub


End sub
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your doing arithmetic functions on strings so really would be a good idea to set option strict on as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement  This will help you avoid these types of issues

Comment: What event is `If Label1.Text = 0 Then` in? If is is not an event then what calls the sub?